# Copy first image file from subfolders into parent and rename

Tags: powershell

Inside a specific folder I have a few sub-folders, in each are stored image files.

I would like to copy the first image file from each sub-folder into the parent  and rename it to the folder's name that it belongs.

I managed to write the following script with the information from several other questions on the site but there is something that is not working as expected. Running the script doesn't copy/rename any file.

```
$Root = (Get-Item -Path '.\' -Verbose).FullName                                        #'

$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $Root -Directory

$Image = Get-ChildItem -Name -Filter *.* | Select-Object -First 1

Foreach($Fld in $Folders)
{
    Copy-Item -Path "$($Fld.FullName)\$Image" -Destination "$Root\$($Fld.Name).jpeg"
}

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

I want to be able to run the script from any folder, the paths must be relative and not absolute/hardcoded. I think the `$Root` variable achieves that purpose.

The sub-folders only contain image files, the filter `*.*` in the `$Image` `Get-ChildItem` is fine for the purpose as it will always pick an image. However the Copy-Item command will copy it with the jpeg extension, is it possible to check the image file extension and copy/rename accordingly? Perhaps with some If statements?

Comment: the `.Name` property of a file is `FileName.ext` ... so there is no need for you to assign one. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mistakenly getting the `$image` in your `$root`-directory since you are using the `get-childitem` without any `-Path` parameter. For your purpose you need `Foreach` `$Fld` (folder) seperately:

```
$Root = (Get-Item -Path '.\' -Verbose).FullName                                        #'

$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $Root -Directory

Foreach($Fld in $Folders)
{
    $Image = Get-ChildItem -Path $Fld -Name -Filter *.* | Select-Object -First 1

    Copy-Item -Path "$($Fld.FullName)\$Image" -Destination "$Root\$($Fld.Name).jpeg"
}

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Here is you code a little shortened:

```
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Directory # Without -path you are in the current working directory

Foreach($Fld in $Folders)
{
    $Image = Get-ChildItem -Path $Fld -Filter *.* | Select-Object -First 1    # Without the -name you get the whole fileinfo

    Copy-Item -Path $Image.FullName -Destination "$PWD\$($Fld.Name)$($Image.Extension)"    # $PWD is a systemvariable for the current working directory
}

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

You could be even bolder as the FullName of the folder contains the path:

```
Copy-Item -Path $Image.FullName -Destination "$($Fld.FullName)$($Image.Extension)"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me the error and cleaning the code. It really makes sense now and worked as expected.